# Como exibir um PDF no browser com um requisição ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, rest

Faço uma requisição assim:

```
$.ajax({type : 'GET', url : URL_APP_CONSULTA_BOLETO_DIVIDA_ATIVA + url});
```

Tenho um método java que retorna algo assim:

```
return (Response.ok(output).header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = " + filename).type( "application/pdf").build());
```

Se olharmos no http temos o seguinte:

```
Request URL:http://xxxxx:8080/app/ConsultaDividaAtiva/boleto/100008621/3npm54
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=6EE1049F45C246F7AB91CD196BC6ADF5
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/view-app/EmiteBoletoDividaAtiva.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
content-disposition:attachment; filename = boleto_20022014115213.pdf
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 20 Feb 2014 14:52:13 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)/JBossWeb-2.0;
```

A pergunta é: como exibir/baixar o PDF retornado pelo serviço REST em java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é viável usar Ajax para exibir um PDF. O que você precisa é apenas abrir uma nova janela ou criar um frame apontando para a URL que retorna o PDF. O browser automaticamente irá fazer uma requisição `GET`.

## Usando `iframe`

Uma solução simples é criar um `iframe` num local adequado na página atual cujo `src` (URL) aponta para o serviço que retorna o PDF via requisição `GET`.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document.body).append(
    '<iframe src="http://www.forelise.com/media/for_elise_sheet_music.pdf">');
```

Se seu sistema não utiliza navegação tradicional entre páginas, não se esqueça remover o elemento adicionado para liberar os recursos alocados.

## Nova janela

Outra opção simples é abrir o relatório numa nova janela, seja através de um link com `target="blank"` ou através de uma popup via Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

É mais simples do que aparenta ser.
Acredito que deva ser um evento click de um botão, caso sim, o trecho de código que faz baixar o arquivo pode ser um simples

```
location.href = "http://xxxxx:8080/app/ConsultaDividaAtiva/boleto/100008621/3npm54";
```

O navegador vai ser direcionado para o arquivo, mas fará o download ao invés de abrir, pois os headers do servidor já estão fazendo isso.

Comment: revivendo esse post sera que eu consigo fazer isso para arquivos não publicados ou seja  que não estão na pasta do meu projeto neles são acessados via um a URL