# Como faço para abrir um pdf dentro de um modal? Pode ser em jQuery e JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Procurei em alguns lugares e não consegui achar uma solução, alguém teria uma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: [Como exibir um PDF no browser com um requisição ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6699/91), [Visualização de PDF no navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8411/91) e [Visualização de PDF em iframe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10505/91)